# ASP.NET MVC 2 AJAX dilemma: Lose Models concept or create unmanageable JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, validation, model, scripting

Ok, let's assume we are working with ASP.NET MVC 2 (latest and greatest preview) and we want to create AJAX user interface with jQuery. So what are our real options here?

**Option 1** - Pass Json from the Controller to the view, and then the view submits Json back to the controller. This means (in the order given):

1. User opens some View (let's say - **/Invoices/January**) which has to visualize a list of data (e.g. `<IEnumerable<X.Y.Z.Models.Invoice>>`)
2. Controller retrieves the Model from the repository (assuming we are using repository pattern).
3. Controller creates a new instance of a class which we will serialize to Json. The reasaon we do this, is because the model may not be serializable (circular reference **ftl**)
4. Controller populates the soon-to-be-serialized class with data
5. Controller serializes the class to Json and passes it the view.
6. User does some change and submits the 'form'
7. The View submits back Json to the controller
8. **The Controller now must 'manually' validate the input, because the Json passed does not bind to a Model**

See, if our View is communicating to the controller via Json, we lose the Model validation, which IMHO is incredible disadvantage. In this case, forget about data annotations and stuff.

**Option 2** - Ok, the alternative of the first approach is to pass the Models to the Views, which is the default behavior in the template when you start a new project.

1. We pass a strong typed model to the view
2. The view renders the appropriate html and javascript, sticking to the model property names. **This is important!**
3. The user submits the form. If we stick to the model names, when we `.serialize()` the form and submit it to the controller it will map to a model.
4. There is no Json mapping. The submitted form directly binds to a strongly typed model, hence, we can use the model validation. E.g. we keep the business logic where it should be.

Problem with this approach is, if we refactor some of the Models (change property names, types, etc), the javascript we wrote would become invalid. We will have to manually refactor the scripting and hope we don't miss something. There is no way you can test it either.

Ok, the question is - how to write an AJAX front end, which keeps the business logic validation in the model (e.g. controller passes and receives a Model type), but in the same time doesn't screw up the javascript and html when we refactor the model?

Answer (score 0):

Stick with Option 2, but there are ways to test the code.  You can use a web application testing tool like [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) to perform integration tests on your HTML pages.  Also, [FireUnit](http://fireunit.org) gives you the ability to unit test your JavaScript code (you'll need Firefox and Firebug in order to use it).

In the spirit of full disclosure, I haven't tried out MVC 2 yet. However, I've been using MVC 1 for some time now and have used these tools with some pretty good results.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem with this approach is, if we
>   refactor some of the Models (change
>   property names, types, etc), the
>   javascript we wrote would become
>   invalid.

I dont see how changing a property of the model changes javascript-code. Usually you hijack the submit event of a form and submit it via ajax. No properies envolved, a long as you take option 2.

Changing properties might break your MVC - application, but thats not specific to ajax.

Comment: Well, what if your javascript dynamically adds and removes items in the form? For example, if we are submitting a list of items. It would be something like:
`<input type='hidden' name='PropertyName[0].Property' id='PropertyName[0]_Property' />`

In this case you will have to redo it, if you change property names.

Comment: Then you realy have a javascript only application. Its ok if you know all your users allow javascript.  But I would not be surprised if you break the scripts when you change the model in this case. The most used way is to have a version that doesnt use javascript and enhance it to an ajax version.

Comment: I see what you mean. The JavaScript should be written in a such way that would make it 'optional' and more of an addon rather than a requirement.

But in reality, how many people disable JavaScripts... We need to draw the line somewhere. You want to use the site - you need to have your JS enabled :)

Anyway, 10x for your opinions.